# MYSQL How find order products matching current storage products (compare two tables for 100% match)

Tags: mysql, laravel

i'm looking for solution to check if multiple rows from one table  have match in other table. In my situation i need to check if items from  orders are in storage. Currently I use php to check orders  - script is taking open orders and foreach one by one to check storage. It's generating quite a lot of queries and it's not efficient at all and i'm looking for solution to do this via sql query.

Desired result should be:

```
OrderId | Date       | Products 

1002/02 | 2020/08/16 | 1x Ipod; 2x battery; 9x some item;

0333/4  | 2020/06/22 | 10x shelf
```

Storage products table

```
id | id_product | quantity
```

Orders

```
id | reference | id_status | created_at
```

Order Products

```
Id | id_order | quantity | id_storage_product
```

[image]

I've written some code to generate table visible above but result it's not even close to desired.

```
select('orders.id', orders.created_at','orders.reference', 'storage_products.id as storageProductId')
                ->join('order_products', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_products.id_order')
                ->join('storage_products', 'order_products.id_product', '=', 'storage_products.id_product')
                ->where('storage_products.quantity', '>=', 'order_products.quantity')
                ->whereIn('orders.id_status', array(1, 2))  //get new orders/ open
                ->where('order_products.id_storage_product', null) 
                ->groupBy('orders.id');
```

Clean sql:

```
SELECT `orders`.`id`,
       `orders`.`created_at`,
       `orders`.`reference`,
       `storage_products`.`id` AS `storageProductId`,
       `order_products`.`id_order`
FROM   `orders`
       INNER JOIN `order_products`
               ON `orders`.`id` =
                  `order_products`.`id_order`
       INNER JOIN `storage_products`
               ON `order_products`.`id_product` =
                  `storage_products`.`id_product`
WHERE  `storage_products`.`quantity` >=
              'order_products.quantity'
       AND `orders`.`id_status` IN ( 1, 2 )
       AND `order_products`.`id_storage_product` IS NULL
GROUP  BY `orders`.`id`
ORDER  BY `orders`.`id` ASC
```

So code should find open orders (id_status); where storage quantity is equal or greater than product in order; where id_storage_products is null (means product bought on website but it was not in storage when ordered).
Upper query result is  wrong because it showed me partial match to storage - even without checking quantity (some products have 0 but still displayed).

For any help many thanks

EDIT: fiddle sample: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6jKvKXPYvsLeXgm3Qv1nHu/0

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirement. It looks like you want a result set with one row for each shippable order-- each order for which all products are already in stock (storage).  Is that correct? (I'm having a hard time understanding the last paragraph of your question.)

Comment: Here is a fiddle - i hope it's far more clear: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6jKvKXPYvsLeXgm3Qv1nHu/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query contains the condition:

```
AND `order_products`.`id_storage_product` IS NULL
```

but in your sample data all values are `0`.
So instead I use `COALESCE()` to cover both cases.
Also I removed the condition:

```
AND `orders`.`id_status` IN ( 1, 2 )
```

because the column `id_status` is not included in the definition of the table `orders` in your sample data.

This query works:

```
SELECT o.id,
       o.reference,
       o.created_at,
       GROUP_CONCAT(op.quantity, 'x', op.id_product separator ' ;') products
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN order_products op ON o.id = op.id_order
INNER JOIN storage_products sp ON op.id_product = sp.id_product
WHERE sp.quantity >= op.quantity AND COALESCE(op.id_storage_product, 0) = 0
GROUP  BY o.id, o.reference, o.created_at
ORDER  BY o.id ASC
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9oDnudxrobdUEwjxL95MiY/1).
Results:

```
| id  | reference | created_at          | products      |
| --- | --------- | ------------------- | ------------- |
| 2   | 345554/02 | 2020-08-22 00:00:00 | 3x188 ; 1x155 |
```

If you also join the table `products` (I assume there is such a table) you can get the names of the products instead of their ids.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following query on the db-fiddle link and this works.

```sql
SELECT
    orders.reference, orders.created_at, order_products.id_product
FROM
    storage_products 
LEFT JOIN 
    order_products ON storage_products.id_product = order_products.id_product 
LEFT JOIN
    orders ON orders.id = order_products.id_order;
```

What I did in the query is calling all storage_products with the same `id_product` in order_products and proceed to call all orders in the called order_products.